clarification about the notion of reduct
In his notes "basics of o-minimality and Hardy field", Miller proves the following result :

Let $\Re_0$ be the reduct of $\Re$ generated over $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by $f \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_{\mathrm{df}}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$. Then $Q E$ fails for $\mathfrak{R}_0$ unless every $f \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_{\mathrm{df}}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ is definable in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

where $\Re$ is a polynomialy bounded o-minimal explansion of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, and $C_{\mathrm{df}}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ is the set of smooth definable functions.
My Questions :

I know about the notion of reduct of a structure, but what about a reduct generated over a substructure?
Does the word unless mean if and only if ?
In the proof he assumes that $\Re_0$ has QE and he takes an arbitrary continuous function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ definable in $\Re_0$ and he shows that it is definable in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, thats it!. How does this prove the claim?

Some vocabulary
A a polynomialy bounded o-minimal explansion of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is an expansion of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ where every definable set in the one dimension is a finite union of points and open intervals and such that every unary definable function is ultimately bounded by $x^N$ for some $N$

"$P$ unless $Q$" means $\lnot Q\implies P$. For example: Let $n$ be a positive integer which is even. Then $n$ is composite, unless $n = 2$.

@AlexKruckman: You sure about that? I would say that $P$ unless $Q$ means $\neg P\implies Q$. (:
